# using slug with bcrypt laravel 5?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

in my code controler post

```
  $data['slug'] = bcrypt($request->title);
  $insert = Video::create($data);
```

in my route

```
Route::get('/watch/{slug}', 'IndexController@watch');
```

in my controoler get slug

```
    public function watch($slug){
      $videos = Video::where('slug',$slug)->first();
      $exist = Rating_video::where('lokit_video_id', $videos->id)->first();
      return view('bnpt.content.video', compact('videos', 'exist'));
   }
```

in my blade

```
 <a href="{{ url('/watch', $data->slug) }}" class="" style="color: white">selengkapnya</a>
```

[image]
when i try the code above instead it gets an error not found, how do i use slug with bcrypt or by using a token?

Comment: **%24** is the Url encoded character for **$**. I think its **decrypt** and **encrypt**, not bcrypt https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/encryption

Comment: I tried to use decrypt and encrypt but instead an error occurred like String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column how do I limit the decrypt and encrypt it?

Comment: Here the problem on the route.  What you get on `localhost:8000/watch/demo`? Change your route to `Route::get('watch/{slug}'…` thete the first slash

Comment: bcrypt is a hashing function, while you idea is good, it is not a good candidate for url slugs since it will have url unsafe characters such as `$`. If you insist on using bcrypt you need to look for ways to encode url. that %24 you see is probably a a `$` overridden. Why not use a `uuid` instead?

Comment: When you use bcrypt you can't just use the given parameter from the URL to directly fetch the data. You might want to see how Laravel uses Bcrypt when you are trying to login to understand how bcrypt works.

Comment: this is already the way i am using md5 helper, thanks for everything for helping me to overcome this problem

Comment: There's no reason to use `bcrypt` to generate a slug. You can just use `Str::random(xx)` or something like this. Using `bcrypt` to hash the title does not offer any utility. It makes URLs look bad, and doesn't really offer much in terms of security